# Bundle/Cache de ficheiros CSS em PHP

Tags: php, algoritmo, hash, cache

Estou a desenvolver um mecanismo em `PHP` que realiza uma cache de ficheiros `CSS` de forma a diminuir o número de `requests` de uma página e o tempo de carregamento.

O mecanismo avalia numa primeira entrada se existe algum ficheiro de cache no servidor para o conjunto de ficheiros `CSS` a carregar e se não existir irá criar um ficheiro que é único e que incluí o conteúdo de todos os ficheiros `CSS`.

Para o nome do ficheiro utilizo uma hash que resulta da avaliação do conteúdo de cada ficheiro. Assim se algum mudar um caracter que seja um novo ficheiro será gerado, o que só acontecerá durante o desenvolvimento e se mexer com `CSS`.

Este mecanismo é bem mais vantajoso do que ter um request por cada `CSS`. Consegue-se diminuir em muito o tempo de load de uma página e em especial o número de requests da mesma.

No entanto a avaliação de uma hash para cada ficheiro `CSS` é **time consuming** mas  para mim parece-me a única forma de garantir que se algum `CSS` alterar, a cache, terá sempre o conteúdo esperado. Utilizo por questões de performance a função `hash_file` dentro de um ciclo:

```
$fhash .= hash_file('crc32b', $filepath);
```

Existe alguma função melhor em termos de performance para este trabalho? Alguém conhece outro mecanismo ou algoritmo?

Sendo certo que o CSS só é modificado em desenvolvimento e nunca em produção não será melhor avaliar uma hash pelo conjunto dos nomes de ficheiros CSS a carregar, eliminando a avaliação de conteúdo?

Comment: Não sei se traz luz ao seu problema, mas ja considerou usar [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filemtime.php) para criar o *hash* baseado em quando o conteúdo do arquivo foi modificado?

Comment: @PapaCharlie ora aí está uma boa questão! Mas parece-me uma boa opção...nem sei como não me lembrei disso. Vou testar e vou ver a diferença no desempenho. Depois digo-lhe alguma coisa... Se lembrar de algo mais agradeço e muito a sua ajuda!

Comment: @PapaCharlie efetivamente obtenho um ganho real cerca de 30% no projeto onde testei que irá certamente resultar num ganho muito bom em servidor com muitos requests! Não quer colocar o seu comentário em resposta para eu poder valorizar a sua resposta? E juntar mais alguma ideia... :)

Comment: Esse ganho de `30%` é bem significativo. Dei uma resposta simples, depois vou testar alguma coisa a mais e atualizo a resposta. :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie testei noutro projeto onde tenho a carregar uns 8 CSS e alguns do tipo JQUERY-UI entre outros está muuuuuuito bom... :)  Passou a um request apenas, com tempo de load em média de 19ms. Vou tb implementar num framework MVC que estou a desenvolver. A sua dica foi importante!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente quando trabalho com cache, considero a data de alteração do arquivo determinante, então, uma alternativa seria a criação de um hash usando [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filemtime.php) baseado no timestamp de quando o conteúdo do arquivo foi modificado pela ultima vez.

> Esta função retorna o tempo quando o bloco de informação de um arquivo foi inicialmente escrito, isto é, o tempo quando o conteúdo do arquivo foi modificado.
>
> Retorna o tempo da última modificação do arquivo, ou FALSE em caso de um erro. O tempo é retornado como um Unix timestamp, que é apropriado para função date()

```
echo filemtime( 'style.css' )
// 1427338769 - output inicial
// 1439229908 - output após a alteração do arquivo

// aplicando o HASH, output: e2510ea8
echo hash( 'crc32b' , filemtime( 'style.css' ) )
```

Comment: claramente uma dica que melhorou o meu tempo de execução! Tenho pena de poder só votar uma vez. nesta. Vou manter a pergunta aberta para ver se obtenho mais algumas dicas... mas a sua foi direito ao problema.

Comment: @chambelix, tentei fazer um bench no Ideone mas não rolou a leitura dos arquivos.

Comment: tens mesmo de notar a diferença pois o hash_file vai avaliar o conteúdo e devolve a hash do mesmo enquanto filemtime obtem o timestamp da "allocation table" que o sistema tem em memória. muuuuito mais rápido. a tua dica está sem dúvida melhor. não sei como não me lembrei disso. :)

Comment: @chambelix, sim, removi o comentário... estava processando outro pensamento e misturou uma coisa com outra... rs